# Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'dispositivosForm'"

Tags: angular, typescript

**Edit 1:** I'm pretty sure (not 100% certain though) the error lies within the formArrayName declaration, as building the form without it yields positive results. Could this be something related to the form not navigating the formArray correctly?

---

I have the following errors when trying to build a dynamic formarray with data from my database

```
ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'dispositivosForm -> 0'"
ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'dispositivosForm -> 1'"
ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'dispositivosForm -> 2'"
[...]
```

all the way to 11 approx.

I've searched in threads with similar issues but none of them were helpful in my case.

What I'm trying to do is to add an edit form which uses the FormArray to pre-select certain options in the select fields I'm building based on data retrieved from DB.

Right now the data is being retrieved and (apparently) stored on the FormArray without issues. But when I try to display the select fields, it breaks and gives the above error.

This edit form shares space with the create form, that's why I'm looping through dispositivosByClase and clase.dispositivo to generate empty fields for the user to interact with.

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div formArrayName="dispositivosForm" *ngFor="let clase of dispositivosByClases; index as i;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <h6>{{ clase.nombre }}</h6>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label></mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="dispositivos" multiple>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let dispo of clase.dispositivos" [value]="dispo.id">
                        {{ dispo.descripcion }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
  equipoForm: FormGroup;
  dispositivos: any = [];
  dispositivosByClases = [];
  dispoArray = [];
  dispoArrayValue = [];
  labelDispositivos: any[] = [];
  dispositivosForm: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
```

.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Inicializa campos
    this.equipoForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      numero_cupi: [''],
      numero_serie: [''],
      descripcion: [''],
      dispositivosForm: [],
      numero_licencia_window: [],
      codigo: ['', [Validators.required]],
      partida_id: [''],
      partida: ['', [Validators.required]],
      enable: [true],
    });
```

.

```
prepareClaseDispositivo() {
    this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
      if (!this.labelDispositivos.includes(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre)) {
        this.labelDispositivos.push(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre);
      }
    });
    this.labelDispositivos.forEach(clase => {
      const dispositivosByClase = [];
      this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
        if (clase === dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre) {
          if (this.data.dispositivos) {
            for (const d of this.data.dispositivos) {
              if (d.descripcion === dispo.descripcion) {
                this.dispoArrayValue.push(dispo);
              }
            }
          }
          dispositivosByClase.push(dispo);
        }
      });
      this.dispositivosByClases.push({ nombre: clase, dispositivos: dispositivosByClase });
      if (this.data.edit) {
        this.dispoArrayForm();
      }
    });
    this.dispositivosForm.push(this.generateFormGroup(this.dispoArrayValue));
    console.log(this.dispositivosForm);
  }
```

.

```
  generateFormGroup(dispo: any) {
    return new FormGroup({
      dispositivos: new FormControl(this.dispoArrayValue)
    });
  }
```

FormArray output:

```
{…}
​
_onCollectionChange: function _onCollectionChange()​
_onDisabledChange: Array []
​
asyncValidator: null
​
controls: Array [ {…} ]
​
errors: null
​
pristine: true
​
status: "VALID"
​
statusChanges: Object { _isScalar: false, closed: false, isStopped: false, … }
​
touched: false
​
validator: null
​
value: (1) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
dispositivos: (1) […]
​​​​
0: Object { id: "eyJpdiI6InFQYTJEbmpENm9lVCsrVVdxZEo3eUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSTVIaVwvRHVXOFdvS2h6TXNaeURsNHc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFiMGJlNmI1NzQ1NGFiZGQ2ZDhjZDJlMzE3MmY1NmYyOTBmMTg1YjdlNTk3OTA3Y2MzMjQwZDEwNzNlZjMwNzgifQ==", descripcion: "9", enable: true, … }
​​​​
length: 1
​​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 1
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
valueChanges: Object { _isScalar: false, closed: false, isStopped: false, … }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
equipo-new-edit.component.ts:155:12
```

Comment: I think you should be looping through your dispositivosForm.controls..

Comment: Where exactly? I've tried setting it as the formArrayName but that didn't work. On the other hand, dispositivoByClase and clase.dispositivo are being looped like that in case the user is adding a new entry instead of editing it, so the form elements appear even if there's no database entries matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in your HTML:

```html
<div formArrayName="dispositivosForm" *ngFor="let clase of dispositivosByClases; index as i;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <!--
            ...
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Did you mean

```html
<div formArrayName="dispositivosForm">
    <div *ngFor="let clase of dispositivosByClases; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <!--
            ...
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I moved the `*ngFor` to the `<div>` of the `formGroupName`, since what you were doing is create multiple `<div>`s for your `dispositivosForm` with only one `<div>` bound to your `formGroupName` according to your index, instead of one `<div>` for your `dispositivosForm` and multiple `<div>`s for each index.

Comment: No luck. Error seems to come from the `formArrayName` tag from what I can see, if that's correct I'm not sure why. Maybe it's trying to run through the formArray in a wrong way or something like that?

Comment: @Kurisu could you edit your post and paste `dispositivosForm`'s value to be somehow more readable? It's really hard to understand. Also, try to show all of its children controls, please.